# Java can't save my input. See my code

Tags: java, list

```
class History  {

    public String[] history;

    public History(String[] history) {
       if (history == null)
           history = new String[]{};
       else 
           history = this.history
    }

}
```

It just keep saving null down no matter what i give it..
So can't work with it..

Comment: new String[]{} == no dimension array == no actual use whatsoever. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do in the code ? i think the assignments should be this.history = ... in both if and else.

Comment: My program have to run even if it get a null input therefore i have create if (history == null)
           history = new String[]{};

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't you mean this?

```
else this.history = history;
```

You also have a mistake in this line:

```
history = new String[]{};
```

It should be:

```
this.history = new String[]{};
```

When I program, I never give local variables the same name as class variables. It only leads to confusion.

Comment: Omg i been trying every i thought i did that too :s

Comment: Don't just upvote so quickly without thinking.  We have also missed the `history = new String[]{};` line.

Comment: @Swupper I spent 2 hours today debugging a case where I had written (in javascript) `if (item.searchIn == item.searchIn)` instead of `if (searchIn == item.searchIn)`. Often when programming it is the silly little mistakes that take the longest time to sort out.

Comment: this.history = new String[]{} ofc.. :)

Answer (score 5):

**Use `this.history` to refer to the class variable and `history` to refer to the method argument.**

You have these being confused, and it's not setting the member variable properly.  When you refer to `history`, this means the argument to the method, not the member variable.

```
public History(String[] history)
{
    if (history == null)
        this.history = new String[]{};
    else
        this.history = history;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For assignment, use

```
this.history = history
```

instead. I think there is a naming conflict between the local variable and the object attribute.